# Pyautogui/python eating tons of memory

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui

So I was making a python script that clicked a spot on my screen, using AI to get positions. Simple as that. However I got a error saying I used ALL of my memory. I realize that when I left the script on it used about a gigabyte every 10 seconds.

Here is my code:

```py
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import gc
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(999999999)
num = 1
def take_screenshot():
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    screenshot = np.array(screenshot)
    return cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

def find_and_click_text():
    template_image = "C:/Users/Owner/template2.png"
    screenshot = take_screenshot()
    template = cv2.imread(template_image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    h, w = template.shape[:-1]

    result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

    if max_val > 0.8:  # Adjust this threshold based on your needs
        top_left = max_loc
        bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
        pyautogui.keyDown('fn')
        pyautogui.keyDown('f12')
        pyautogui.moveTo((top_left[0] + w/2, top_left[1] + h/2))
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
        pyautogui.click()
        skip()
    else:
        global num
        num += 1     
        if num >= 10:
            skip()
            num = 0
        else:
         find_and_click_text()
def skip():
    skipurl = "C:/Users/Owner/skip2.png"
    screenshot2 = take_screenshot()
    template2 = cv2.imread(skipurl, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    h, w = template2.shape[:-1]

    result2 = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot2, template2, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val2, min_loc, max_loc2 = cv2.minMaxLoc(result2)

    if max_val2 > 0.8:
        top_left2 = max_loc2
        bottom_right2 = (top_left2[0] + w, top_left2[1] + h)
        pyautogui.keyDown('fn')
        pyautogui.keyDown('f8')
        pyautogui.moveTo((top_left2[0] + w/2, top_left2[1] + h/2))
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
        pyautogui.click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        find_and_click_text()
    else:
        global num
        num += 1
        if num >= 10:
            find_and_click_text()
            num = 0
        else:
            skip()

find_and_click_text()
```

I'm new to Python (like literally today new), but I am experienced in web development, so I got the jist. I was wondering if this was a optimisation problem or I'm just really dumb?

Edit:
So I think my solution is just to stop the script every 3 minutes 15 seconds (I timed it, it takes around 8gbs memory) and start it again. It releases the memory and I can keep going. This isnt easy though because the whole point is that it is automated. How would I be able to stop the script wait like 5 or 10 seconds and start it again? Maybe this would be like time.sleep or something. Im very new to Python

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a escape clause. You are using recursion in any possible case. When does your program ends?
In addition, setting 999,999,999 is excessive.

Comment: it doesn’t end. haha

Comment: Probably the answer to this questions helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop